# Change the inbox notification text for mod messages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, moderator-messages

When another moderator sends a message to a user, the inbox notification says:

> moderator message on *AviD added a new message*
>
> Hello, I'm writing in reference to your IT Security - Stack Exchange account: `http://securi...`

Everytime I get this notification, it makes me jump!

It should say this instead:

> moderator message from *[modname]♦ to [username]*

This makes it clear, that I am not the recipient of the message.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess if we had more of them we'd get used to it. Luckily we don't...

Comment: What do mod message notifications look like now for the recipient? Is this request still applicable?

Comment: @V2Blast Notifications for a mod messages currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ZCQ.png). That's a mod message I sent to one of my test accounts back in October, but the image is from today. Without a better description of what the issue is that this question is trying to address, I'd either close this question as unclear/needs details, or consider it [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Makyen: Sounds good. Since it's not entirely clear what "made [the author] jump" about the notification – it could be the weirdly titled heading of "moderator message on AviD added a new message", but it could also be the fact that the body text starts with the "I'm writing in reference to your [site] account" – I'll close it as unclear.

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah, that's largely what I consider unclear. Personally, I'm undecided if skipping that text is helpful in the inbox or not. It's certainly helpful to skip that text in the summary listings mods see, where showing that text is distracting, but I'd expect it would be useful in the inbox for users who've received only a single mod message, but if there's more than one mod message, then the text after that intro is what's useful to distinguish between them. OTOH, it's not reasonable to expect the system to show a different summary based on the number of mod messages the user's received.

Comment: @V2Blast. The message from the other moderator says "I'm writing in reference to **your** [site] account" But this is neither about my account nor is the message for me. Therefore I propose to include the username of the recipient in the notification. PS: This feature request is more than 11 years old and I have retired from moderation a long time ago. The message might look different today.

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann: Ah, thanks. I just came across this post while looking through posts related to mod messages (I think) and wanted to clarify whether it should be marked as done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been implemented somewhere in the past; it's now like this:

> ##### moderator message
>
> [moderator] sent [reason] (with edits) to [recipient]

(the (with edits) part is optional, that's shown when you edited the template)

The screenshot below shows some other possible notifications regarding moderator messages as well.

[image: screenshot of moderator inbox, names redacted]

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, that message is a bit weird, but your alternative is a bit boring. How about:

> [modname] ♦ brought the hammer down on [username]

Comment: Anything that makes it clear that I am not the one banned.

Comment: @HendrikBrummermann Why? Even if you do get banned, you can unsuspend yourself you know ;)

Comment: Reeeheeellly?? @HendrikBrummermann we have to try that!